# Fetching top 5 records of maximum salary

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns with id,usrnameand salary. I want to find maximum salary of 5 records.
How will i write query in mysql ?

Answer (score 8):

In MySQL you can use ORDER BY to sort the rows in descending order and use LIMIT to return only the top 5 rows:

```
SELECT id, usrname, salary
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LIMIT, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 5
```